# How can I control the x position of the ends of geom_errorbars without using aes() to define the position of the errorbars?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I am creating a graph and then adding error bars along the graph. The position of the error bars depends on the first graph. The number of error bars I graph must also be able to change(hence the for loop).

```
df <- data.frame(x=1:10,y=sample(1:10,10,replace = TRUE))
plot <- ggplot(df)+
  geom_line(aes(x,y))
plot.data <- ggplot_build(plot)$data[[1]]

plot #first plotting
```

After the initial graph is made, all looks well:[image]

To add the errorbars (in this example, the range of the values < i*2)

```
for(i in 1:5){
  plot<- plot + geom_errorbar(x=i*2,ymin = min(plot.data$y[plot.data$x <= i*2]),ymax = max(plot.data$y[plot.data$x <= i*2]),width = 1,color = "blue")
}
plot #second plotting
```

[image: This abomination]

I want to be able to control the x position of the ends of the error bars. I want them to be where the vertical part of the error_bar is, and I have no idea why some are at x=~6 and some at x=~20

When I tried adding `aes()` around my `x,ymin,ymax`:

```
for(i in 1:5){
  plot<- plot + geom_errorbar(aes(x=i*2,ymin = min(plot.data$y[plot.data$x <= i*2]),ymax = max(plot.data$y[plot.data$x <= i*2]),width = 1),color = "blue")
}
plot
```

Only the final error_bar was plotted, although with the ends in the right position. 
[image]

I understand that the ends of the error_bars can be manipulated with aes(), but I cannot use that as it does not replicate in a loop, only the last iteration is plotted.
Additionally, what is currently determining the x position of the ends of the error_bars? The numbers ~6.5 and ~21 do not appear in any of my data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't add the error bars in a loop. First create a dataframe with the x, ymin and ymax values as columns, then call `geom_errorbar` once on that dataframe.

```
i = 1:5
err.data = data.frame(x = i * 2)
for (j in i) {
  err.data[j, 'ymin'] = min(df$y[df$x <= j*2])
  err.data[j, 'ymax'] = max(df$y[df$x <= j*2])
} 

plot +
  geom_errorbar(aes(x,ymin=ymin,ymax=ymax), data=err.data, color='blue')
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this is the obvious solution once I think about it. Any idea why the bars were behaving the way they did? What about the loop made them do that?